# Dask Dataframe Greater than a Delayed Number

Tags: dask

Is there a way to do this but with the threshold as a delayed number?

```
import dask
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

threshold = 3

df = pd.DataFrame({'something': [1,2,3,4]})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

ddf[ddf['something'] >= threshold]
```

What if `threshold` is:

```
threshold = dask.delayed(3)
```

Atm it gives me:

```
TypeError('Truth of Delayed objects is not supported')
```

I want to keep the `ddf` as a dask dataframe, and not turn it into a pandas dataframe. Wondering if there was combinator forms that also took delayed values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dask has no way to know that the concrete value in that Delayed object is an integer, so there's no way to know what to do with it in the operation (align, broadcast, etc.)

If you use something like a size-0 array, things seem OK

```
In [32]: df = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 4]}), 2)

In [33]: threshold = da.from_array(np.array([3]))[0]

In [34]: df.A > threshold
Out[34]:
Dask Series Structure:
npartitions=2
0    bool
2     ...
3     ...
Name: A, dtype: bool
Dask Name: gt, 8 tasks

In [35]: df[df.A > threshold].compute()
Out[35]:
   A
3  4
```

Comment: Me too!  Maybe you can help to implement it.